# VBA Excel, recorrer fila de columna con suma de valor anterior

Tags: excel, vba, recursión

Por favor, compartan un poco de su conocimiento, como puedo hacer para que se sume un valor 'N' a una celda con un valor ya dado, y que el valor N se sume con la primer celda, y el resultado se coloque en la celda B2, y al valor de la celda B2 se le sume el valor N, y el resultado se coloque en la celda C2 y asi subsecuentemente.

Gracias por su atencion !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Con un `bucle` se puede efectuar lo que requieres. VBA cuenta con tres tipos de bucles básicos: `Do Until {...} Loop`, `Do While {...} Loop` y `For {...} Next`. Si estás iniciando mi recomendación es que emplees el último de ellos para evitar un bucle infinito, porque los dos primeros trabajan con condiciones. Acá hay un tutorial en español para [el bucle For Next en VBA](https://excelyvba.com/el-bucle-for-next/). Otra recomendación sería que los valores no vayan horizontales sino verticales, así evitamos el `messy data`, aunque esto último no está relacionado con la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es simplemente crear una fórmula y arrastrar. Si N siempre va a ser 9, entonces puedes meterlo directamente en la fórmula. Si N es personalizable, entonces mételo en una celda aparte, y referencias a la celda en tu formula (fijando con $).

Un ejemplo. Yo he diseñado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la celda `B1` es donde especificas el valor que quieres que tenga n (el incremento)

En la celda `B3` especificas el valor inicial.

Mi fórmula en `A7` es `=B3`

Mi fórmula en `A8` es `=A7+$B$1`

Con arrastrar hacia abajo desde `A8`, la propia fórmula incrementa el valor superior en n (en este ejemplo, n=9).

Te he subido el archivo a mi Google Drive, por si quieres descargarlo y mirar las fórmulas. Espero que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ja-ddZ5B2cBpj-OFQrPyadgQXAnBenB1

Por si quieres profundizar en crear series en Excel, te dejo un enlace oficial:

> **[Proyectar valores en una serie](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/proyectar-valores-en-una-serie-5311f5cf-149e-4d06-81dd-5aaad87e5400)**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Elier bastante funcional, encontre una similitud a tu sintaxis pero un poco más primivita, seria colocar en la celda de `A8` lo siguiente `=(A7)+9` y arrastrar hacia abajo. Sin duda tu solución tiene mejores respultados si hay necesidad de cambiar el valor incremental. Saludos.